# Design heuristics for writing Python classes that interact with `scipy.integrate.odeint`?

Tags: python, design-patterns, scipy, numba

### Introduction

[`scipy.integrate.odeint`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) requires as its first argument, a function that computes the derivatives of the variables we want to integrate over (which I'll refer to as `d_func`, for "derivative function" from now on).

`d_func` has to be written by the user, in Python code. A great way to get a boost of performance using Numba is to `@jit` the `d_func` (because `d_func`  is called *many* times during integration).

I have questions about how to write performant code when `d_func` is complicated enough that it needs a Python class object behind it.

### Code setup

Here is a "cartoon" of my code:

- there is a module called `DynamicBox.py`
- inside this module is a Python class, `DynamicBox`
- `DynamicBox` has a bunch of attributes
- some of these attributes are "phase variables" -- that is, *they* are the quantities I am interested in integrating
- some of these attributes are "parameters" -- that is, I use them to
  calculate the derivatives of the phase variables

I will have a bunch of functions that will take `DynamixBox` phase variable or parameter attributes, in order to calculate relevant terms in the derivatives. That is:

- I will have a `d_func`
- `d_func` itself will call lots of little helper functions to
  calculate relevant terms in the derivative, using `DynamixBox`
  attributes

### Design choices

I have to make a choice, with the following options:

1. either I can make `d_func` and all its helper functions methods of
   `DynamicBox`;
2. or I can make only `d_func` a method of `DynamicBox`,
       and all of its helper functions are in the same module as
       `DynamicBox`, but not methods of `DynamicBox`;
3. or only the helper functions are methods of `DynamicBox`, but
   `d_func` is just in the same module (`DynamicBox.py`), and not a
   method of `DynamicBox`;
4. or neither the helper functions, nor d_func, are methods of
   DynamicBox.

### Question

I do not know enough about Python to figure out which choice is best. The following questions I think would need answering.

- **Is it expensive to make instance attribute calls to get attributes or is it expensive only if you are in a function that is not a method
  of the class?**
- **What if Numba is in play? For instance, will Numba like it better if I am `@jit`-ting normal functions instead of class methods?**

Comment: Attributes are an overhead regardless of how you access them. Using `__slots__` *might* help, but I don't know for sure (that's why I post this as a comment). Should you proceed with option 1, consider using `__call__`.

Comment: If you're using Numba, you can't currently use numba with class methods. Also any class attribute access will throw it into the much slower "object mode", so you probably can't do that (unless you have a loop afterwards it can compile separately which will constitute the main speed-up)

Comment: As for an somewhat unrelated design heuristic: Try Sympy (http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/ode.html) first to obtain a closed form solution.

Comment: @Phillip If attributes are an overhead (assuming using `__slots__` doesn't help), then I guess that means that I should be using Cython (for the struct-like `cdef class`), or I should avoid trying to use object oriented structure for my code, or I could just use C++? Are those essentially my choices?

Comment: @Dietrich I don't think SymPy can solve systems of non-linear ODEs, can it? I would love it if it could!

Comment: Sympy can solve some (special) types of nonlinear ODE-systems - see the docs for those (http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/ode.html#system-of-odes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can comment on the Numba portion of this question.

As other users have mentioned, attribute access in Numba leads to some overhead. For example, you might be tempted to write code like this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    @numba.jit
    def dosomething(self, y):
        for i in range(len(self.x)):
            self.x[i] += y[i]
```

This will be slow, because Numba has to call into the Python layer for attribute access each time it encounters `self.x`.

A better way to do the same thing would be this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def dosomething(self, y):
        _dosomething(self.x, y)

@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def _dosomething(x, y):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        x[i] += y[i]
```

Here there is no attribute access within the loop, and additionally we're able to add the `nopython=True` argument, which will cause Numba to raise an error if the function has to fall back on any (slow) Python code. This `nopython` argument is a great way to make sure that your Numba functions are as efficient as possible.

Comment: Thanks Jake! So in general, with Numba as stands so far, one should avoid trying to use attribute access, or minimizing it by using "helper functions" as you've suggested. Hopefully, the minimized attribute access calls aren't a bottleneck!

Comment: Yes, though you really should only worry about attribute access (and other slow Python operations) which are repeated many times – i.e. within large loops. Where numba can buy you performance is when you have many repeated small operations, such as arithmetic or array element access. This is where CPython tends to be slow.